# Scene mirroring every direction

Tags: rendering, mirror, scene

I am doing a simple scene. Whenever I render, there seems to be a strange problem - the scene is mirroring in every direction. I have no idea where it comes from. If you disable the whole collection 1 in render the problem disappears. However, I disabled each individual object in this collection and the problem still persists. I have no idea what to do :([Blender file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qOKF4uTBoiW8iTVmF0TG_xiG1d7wgaVD)
Let me add a rendered movie for You. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-J7c0s8WPE&feature=youtu.be
In the end You can see like a giant mirror wall which is not there in the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Smoke Domain has a weird material.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, all texture types that are not color should have Non-Color Color Space.

[image]

[image]

Some objects probably are missing smooth shading.

[image]

After the changes.

[image]

Comment: Wow, my friend. Thank you. Now I see. Smoke material has a wormhole node setup for it. I must have ctrl+v it by accident to domain material. Now I realize where the hell a smoke has gone in my render... I will remember all the tips you gave me. Thank you for your help! 

Btw. I just realised my scene was a tesseract...